# Using Interfaces as an attribute in TypeScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a class called `Tab` which has three props:

- `num: string`
- `desc: string`
- `parts: Part[]`

where `Part` has this code in `Tab.tsx`:

```
interface Part {
    desc: string,
    link: string
}
```

But when I create a `Tab` in `Menu.tsx` (the parent), I am unsure how to define the parts attribute.

```
<Tab num="1" desc="Description" parts=? />
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: parts is an array of objects `parts={[{desc: 'bla', link: 'foo'}]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parts` is an Array of objects in the shape of `{ desc: string; link: string; }`.

Pass it this way: `[{ desc: "foo", link: "bar" }, { desc: "foo", link: "baz" }]`.

Example:

```
<Tab
 num="1"
 desc="Description"
 parts={[{ desc: "foo", link: "bar" }, { desc: "foo", link: "baz" }]}
/>
```